# The correct way to pass arguments in a child process (execv and excvp)

Tags: c, wsl-2, execvp

I am trying to build a shell in c. I keep getting errors like "Invalid arguments" or "No such file or directory". 
I am on WSL2. Is there any chance the correct path to the file called by execv() is somehow affected by the fact that there is a windows file system behind WSL2? Because if not what is the correct path to bin?
Why "~/bin/" won't work, resulting in a "No such a file or directory" error?
On the other hand, when I am using execvp() which contains the "/usr/local/bin" in $PATH variable, it will only work in the first version shown below and not in the second which creates child processes. Why is that?

The version with no sub-processes:

```
#define N 10 
#define STRLIM 20
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    char cmdName[STRLIM];
    char** args=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*N);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        args[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLIM);
    }
    strcpy(cmdName,"pwd");
    
    int pid=fork();
        if(pid<0){
            printf("fork failed");
        }else if(pid==0){
           if(execvp(cmdName,args)==-1){
               perror("\n EXECVP ERROR:");
           }
          
        }else if(pid>0){
            printf("\nthe pid of the child is : %d\n",pid);
        }else{
            wait(NULL);
        }
        close(pid);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my version:

```
int execute(char** args){  //the args[0] is always the name of the file.
    printf("cmdName is : %s",args[0]);
    pid_t pid=fork();
        if(pid<0){
            printf("fork failed");
            perror(strerror(errno));
        }else if(pid==0){
           if(execvp(args[0],args)<0){ 
               perror("\n EXECVP ERROR:");
               printf(":%s",strerror(errno));
           }   
           exit(0);       
        }else if(pid>0){ 
            if(waitpid(pid,NULL,0)==-1){
                printf("\nerror in wait!!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        close(pid);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I haven't found any manual that specifies if the arguments in the char* argv[] of execv (or execvp) should be separated from the ' - ' or not. These two commands expect an argument format like:

```
argv["ls","-l",NULL]
```

or

```
argv["ls","l",NULL]
```

Which one is it?

Could that be the reason for the computer reporting invalid arguments?
In other words, an argument is processed as "-l" or as "l" ?

This might seem like silly questions, but I have been searching and experimenting for the past 5 hours, so I thought it was about time to ask for help. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `argv["ls","-l",NULL]` will do the same thing as typing `ls -l` at the shell prompt. 
`argv["ls","l",NULL]` will do the same thing as typing `ls l` at the shell prompt. Both make sense, both are valid, depending on what you need.

Comment: `"~/bin/"` won't work because `~` is handled by the shell, not the OS. To `execvp`, `~` is just an ordinary character and `~/bin` is not the name of any directory. You don't show your full code but I see no evidence on your first example that you respect the requirement that the  `argv`  array be terminated with a NULL. (Nor that the individual elements are null-terminated strings.) Non-termination could cause any number of unfortunate consequences. `-l` is not special in any way as an argument. It's just passed to the application as is.

Comment: Instead of `~`, use `getenv("HOME")`.

Comment: Q: Is there any chance the correct path to the file called by execv() is somehow affected by the fact that there is a windows file system behind WSL2?  A: No.  execv() will behave the same.  Q: Why "~/bin/" won't work?  A: Because "~" is a metacharacter interpreted by a *SHELL*.  As far as execvp() is concerned, "~" is just the character "~" - nothing more.  ALSO: Your **args list *MUST* end in a null.

Answer (score 0):

At least this issue:

[The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)

```
// #define N 10 // Not needed
#define STRLIM 20

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int i=0;
    char cmdName[STRLIM];

    // char** args=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*N);
    char** args = malloc(sizeof *args * (argc + 1));  // Note: + 1

    // for(i=0;i<3; i++){
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){  // Loop though all arguments.
        // args[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLIM);
        args[i] = strdup(argv[i]);  // Duplicate the strings.
    }

    // Add!
    args[argc] = NULL;

    ...
```